# HTTP 502 Proxy Error - The size of the response header is too large. Contact your ISA server administrator. (12216)

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, iis-7.5

Some of my users are getting the following error

HTTP 502 Proxy Error - The size of the response header is too large. Contact your ISA server administrator. (12216)
Internet Security and Acceleration Server

I am guessing it has to do with the size of hidden "__ViewState" tag in my ASP.NET pages.

I also realize that this is restriction imposed to by IT on the users end and I have no contol over it.

I disabled ViewState on all the controls in my ASP.NET pages.  However, __ViewState is still generated very large (as always) to persist control-state (e.g. checkbox, radiobutton, etc.)

Is there a workaround that I can try?

Answer (score 0):

First, if ISA is complaining about the response "header" then it's not likely viewstate. Viewstate is "simply" a form field in the body of the page. There are many things you can do to reduce the size of ViewState, along with products that will let you eliminate it from the page response completely (ours at http://www.techsoftinc.com/viewstate being but one of many.)

If you've disabled all the viewstates on the page and it's still "very large" I'd suggest running it through a viewstate decoder to see what's actually in it. Have you perhaps not disabled it on a datagrid or other control that's stashing a ton of data in it?

However beyond ViewState, what's actually in the header of the response? (not the  tag, but the headers that come before the response.) You may need something like fiddler to show you.

Comment: If this is the header, then I am probably wrong blaming the view state. You are probably implying the stuff that appears between then <head> </head> tags in the resulting HTML. How do I know if my header is too large?

Comment: Nope, actually even the stuff between the <head> and </head> tags is still in the body of the HTTP response. ISA is complaining about the _HTTP_ header, not the HTML header. You won't see the HTTP headers in your source code on the server, or in a browser's view-source. You need to see the actual HTTP conversation to see the headers returned.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate the what triggered error, generally it's happens due to file dwld code

Such as response.write.....

Try configuring  web.config.. Max request length .. Sorry for incomplete answer but answered frm mobile that's reason..

Comment: There is no file download operation.

Comment: check this link - http://forums.isaserver.org/m_20529000/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#20529000 might be helpful